# how to get 'on' event listener in ibm-cloud/cloudant package?

Tags: ibm-cloud, event-listener, cloudant

The deprecated @cloudant/cloudant is replaced by ibm-cloud/cloudant package.  In former I was using following code snippet

```
const feed = dummyDB.follow({ include_docs: true, since: 'now'})

feed.on('change', function (change) {
     console.log(change)
   })
feed.on('error', function (err) {
     console.log(err)
})

feed.filter = function (doc, req) {
     if (doc._deleted || doc.clusterId === clusterID) {
       return true
     }
     return false
   }
```

Could you share a code for which I can get feed.on event listener similar to above code in new npm package ibm-cloud/cloudant.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an event emitter for changes in the `@ibm-cloud/cloudant` package right now. You can emulate the behaviour by either:

polling [`postChanges`](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant?code=node#postchanges-databases) (updating the `since` value after new results) and processing the response `result` property, which is a [`ChangesResult`](https://ibm.github.io/cloudant-node-sdk/docs/latest/interfaces/cloudant_v1.ChangesResult.html). That in turn has a `results` property that is an array of [`ChangesResultItem`](https://ibm.github.io/cloudant-node-sdk/docs/latest/interfaces/cloudant_v1.export_.ChangesResultItem.html) elements, each of which is equivalent to the `change` argument of the event handler function.

or

call `postChangesAsStream` with a feed type of `continuous` and process the `stream` returned in the response `result` property, each line of which is a JSON object that follows the structure of `ChangesResultItem`. In this case you'd also probably want to configure a heartbeat and timeouts.

In both cases you'd need to handle errors to reconnect in the event of network glitches etc.